# AndroidStudio: Why are alternative screen-size layouts being ignored?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, screen-size

I am testing the ability to use different layouts directories for different screen sizes ([android training](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)). I am using [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) for my emulators (because I have a windows10 with AMD processor).

My directory structure looks like:

```
MyProject/
  res/
    layout/
        activity_main.xml
    layout-large/
        activity_main.xml
    layout-sw1440dp/
        activity_main.xml
    layout-xlarge/
        activity_main.xml
```

In every version of `activity_main.xml` I have one TextView.

In the normal version I have `android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"`.

In the other three versions I have `android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"`.

So when I test using genymotion's Nexus 6 with resolution: 1440x2560, I would expect to see the TextView at the bottom. But it is always at the top.

*However*, when I am editing one of the large xml's, the Android Studio Preview Pane does show the TextView at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing DP and pixels, they are not the same. The Nexus 6 is indeed 1440x2560, but that translates to 410x730 in DPs.

See [this table](https://design.google.com/devices/) for reference.